# Unintended Parallax effect in nested UICollectionView Scrolling in a parent TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableViewController with embedded collectionView ... Each items of which is either UICollectionView / UITableView.. I need the Parent Tableview to scroll up/down first and only it has completed the child should be scrolled up or down.

I have mostly achieved this but the tableview is not scrolling fully to the bottom (10% remaining) with an unwanted parallax effect while scrolling. I understand this is due to the reason that i am passing the offset from child to parent but i need make the child still so that it only moves with parent and not on its own. But i do not know how to do it.

In the childViewController i did this :

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {


 if(parent.tableView.contentOffset.y >= (parent.tableView.contentSize.height - parent.tableView.frame.size.height)) {
    //

    if self.collectionView?.contentOffset.y <= 0 || self.collectionView?.contentOffset.y >= self.collectionView?.contentSize.height{
    print("Child scrolled the top")
        parent.tableView?.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: true)

    }

 }else {
    print("Parent TableView should move")
    parent.tableView?.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: false)

}
```

This is my Layout
[1.Without Scroll  2.While Scrolling Parellax  3.Scrolled(distance remaining in bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TVig.jpg)

[image]

The height of HomeTableView = view.frame.height and the same for each item in UICollectionView.

Can anyone help me to get full bottom scroll & remove parallax effect.